# Powershell - Assign random number to AD "Telephone" Tab "IP Phone" field

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need help with writing a PowerShell code
I want to generate a Randon number (password) and assign that number to all active users in active directory.
The random number will be place on the "IP Phone" field from the "Telephone" tab in AD to act as a password for secure printing

Comment: ...and you call that *secure*?!?

Comment: We're not a script writing service. What have you tried and what were your results?

Comment: chatgpt will for sure write it, but using this site requires at least the knowledge of [ask]

Comment: Voted to close for unreasonable IT practices.

Comment: Very bad idea. That field is not protected by any means and can be read by everyone

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number with PowerShell is easy:

```
$RandomNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
```

Then you will need to add them in the field with set-AdUser

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Answer (score 0):

#Get a list of all employees.
$searchlist = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=VNA Users,OU=VNA,DC=vnatc,DC=local" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$employeelist = foreach($ou in $searchlist){
get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
}

#####Assigning the Password to the Employee in the Employee List#####
foreach($employee in $employeelist){
$password = Get-Random -Minimum 100000 -Maximum 999999
$password
Set-ADUser -Identity $employee -Replace @{ipPhone=$password} -WhatIf
}

This is what I have written so far.  I need to append this to a CSV file, then assign a passcode to each user.  Hope to get some feedback.